# Matching and unmatching responsive JavaScript with .matchMedia()

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I am having difficulty getting some responsive js to work. I have 5 breakpoints and the desired outcome is that js functions are matched when the breakpoint is active, and unmatched when the breakpoint is no longer active.

Below is the approach I have taken. The problem I am encountering is with the unmatching, it works going from bp1 -> bp5 but not bp5 -> bp1.

Any help is appreciated

```
var breakpoints = {
  bp1: //.....,
  bp2: //.....,
  //.....
  bp5: //.....
};

var queries = {
  bp1: {
    match: function() {
      console.log('smalltouch portrait');
      //...
    },
    unmatch: function() {
      console.log('unmatch smalltouch portrait');
      //...
    },
    active: false
  },
  bp2: {
    match: function() {
      console.log('smalltouch landscape');
      //...
    },
    unmatch: function() {
      console.log('unmatch smalltouch lanscape');
      //...
    },
    active: false
  },
  //.....
  bp5: {
    match: function() {
      console.log('standard desktop');
      //...
    },
    unmatch: function() {
      console.log('unmatch standard desktop');
      //...
    },
    active: false
  }
};  

for (var name in breakpoints){
  // need to scope variables in a for loop
  !function(breakName, query) {

    // the callback
    function cb(data){
      // add class name associated to current breakpoint match
      $('body').toggleClass(breakName, data.matches);

      //unmatch previous matches
      if (data.matches === false && queries[breakName].active) {
        queries[breakName].unmatch();
        queries[breakName].active = false;
      }

      //match to breakpoint
      if (data.matches === true) {
        queries[breakName].match();
        queries[breakName].active = true;
      }

    }    
    // run the callback on current viewport
    cb({
      media: query,
      matches: matchMedia(query).matches
    });
    // subscribe to breakpoint changes
    matchMedia(query).addListener(cb);
  }(name, breakpoints[name]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. I've changed the way the unmatch happens

```
var breakpoints = {
  bp1: //.....,
  bp2: //.....,
  //.....
  bp5: //.....
};

var queries = {
  bp1: {
    match: function() {
      console.log('smalltouch portrait');
      //...
    },
    unmatch: function() {
      console.log('unmatch smalltouch portrait');
      //...
    }
  },
  bp2: {
    match: function() {
      console.log('smalltouch landscape');
      //...
    },
    unmatch: function() {
      console.log('unmatch smalltouch lanscape');
      //...
    }
  },
  //.....
  bp5: {
    match: function() {
      console.log('standard desktop');
      //...
    },
    unmatch: function() {
      console.log('unmatch standard desktop');
      //...
    }
  }
};

var prevBreakpoint = '';

for (var name in breakpoints){
  // need to scope variables in a for loop
  !function(breakName, query) {

    // the callback
    function cb(data){
      // add class name associated to current breakpoint match
      $('body').toggleClass(breakName, data.matches);

      if (data.matches === true) {
        if (prevBreakpoint) {
          queries[prevBreakpoint].unmatch();
        }
        queries[breakName].match();
        prevBreakpoint = breakName;
      }

    }    
    // run the callback on current viewport
    cb({
      media: query,
      matches: matchMedia(query).matches
    });
    // subscribe to breakpoint changes
    matchMedia(query).addListener(cb);
  }(name, breakpoints[name]);
}
```